# Unable to connect MySQL and Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python 3.5 for school project, I also already installed MySQL connector for python. I tried to import the database from MySQL but it says "MySQL module not found.

```
     import mysql.connector
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
       import mysql.connector
 ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
```

How do i solve this? any idea?

Comment: have you mysql module installed? try pip install mysql

Comment: Did you intall mysql module correct? - pip install requires microsoft c++ 9.0 at the moment

Answer (score 0):

is mysql connector installed with python pip 3.5 ?
sometimes default pip is binded to default python, make sure you've installed it for correct version of python